# How to remove search icon from PlaceAutocompleteFragment in Android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using PlaceAutocompleteFragment to search places.
Below is my xml code

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/place_source"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment" />
```

I want to remove search icon which by default comes with fragment.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this single line to get the reference of search icon :`((View)findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_button)).setVisibility(View.GONE);`

and this line to get the reference of EditText: `((EditText)findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input))`

Comment: This works with only one PlaceAutocompleteFragment .I have two PlaceAutocompleteFragment  and it sets for first PlaceAutocompleteFragment

Answer (score 3):

If we have 2 autocompleteFragments, we can hide the icons like this :

```
autocompleteFragment_from.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
autocompleteFragment_to.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions didnt work for me as I was using 2.1.0

The ID's for this version are :

Search Icon : places_autocomplete_search_button

Clear Icon : places_autocomplete_clear_button

Edit Text : places_autocomplete_search_input

So in order to use them simply,

```
autocompleteSupportFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.places_autocomplete_search_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: From which package is that R?

Comment: Oh it was: com.google.android.libraries.places.R

However it seems that the results search_input is different than the one with the final address.

Comment: (places_autocomplete_clear_button) from package : com.google.android.libraries.places.R.id.places_autocomplete_clear_button

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old, but I'll leave this here for future viewers.

While @rajat44's answer solves it when you have one PlaceAutocompleteFragment, if you have multiple you can do this:

```
pacf.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
pacf2.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to customize the look of the `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` unfortunately but, since all it does is launch the PlaceAutocomplete activity in response to taps it's pretty easy to replicate its functionality with a UI that works for your app.

1. Create a custom fragment ([instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)).
2. Add the UI elements you want to the fragment.
3. Add an OnClickListener to the UI elements that starts an autocomplete Activity ([as described in the API docs](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#option_2_use_an_intent_to_launch_the_autocomplete_activity)).

Comment: Actually I am able to get the reference of EditText view used as part of PlaceAutocompleteFragment like  src = ((EditText)placePickup.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input));
        target = ((EditText)placeDrop.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input));