# How to disable search icon from all PlaceAutocompleteFragment?

Tags: android-studio, google-places-api

I have 2 fields in my Layout. PickUp/ Drop

```
autocompleteFragment_pickup = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment_pickup);

autocompleteFragment_pickup = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment_drop);
```

with this code below, i can disable only one icon, but I have 2 Icons. Search-Icon of PickUp and other one of Drop adress.

```
((View)findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_button)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Only the Icon of PickUp will be invisible.

[according to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211272/how-to-remove-search-icon-from-placeautocompletefragment-in-android)