# Not able to remove search button in Auto complete Fragment in android

Tags: android, placeautocompletefragment

I am using auto complete fragment to search location using google places it is working fine. Now i want to remove search icon so used below code but one error is showing. code and error text are below.

**Code sample**

```
autocompleteFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/header">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:background="#1d1d6e"
        android:textColor="#9999f9"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="19dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="ADD LOCATION" />
</LinearLayout>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/flat_no"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Flat Number/House Name"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/locationedittext"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/locationedittext"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/makani"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Search By Makani"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/locationedittext"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/makanibutton"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/makani"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/startbutton"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="SUBMIT"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LOCATION LIST"
            android:textStyle=""
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/locationlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Error Text**

> error: cannot find symbol variable place_autocomplete_search_button

I also want to change the hint text size of auto complete fragment

Comment: can you post your full xml code

Comment: posted full xml code

Comment: you want to hide which button?

Comment: `place_autocomplete_search_button` - where did you get this id?

Comment: inside autocomplete_fragment there is one default search button i want to hidden that search button

Comment: this fragment replaced with which fragment?

Comment: when i search on google it is the only visible way i hidden search button

Comment: [Please use this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211272/how-to-remove-search-icon-from-placeautocompletefragment-in-android)

Comment: can you post source code also

Comment: `AutoCompleteFragment` is deprecated. Please refer https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

> Please migrate to the **latest SDK** and use `AutoCompleteSupportFragment`
>   instead of `AutoCompleteFragment`.
>
> For complete information related to migrating you can refer [here.](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically)

After migrating for hiding the search button the id is,

**places_autocomplete_search_button** for the search `Button`.

**places_autocomplete_search_input** for the `EditText`.

So your code will be somewhat similar to this,

```
autocompleteSupportFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.places_autocomplete_search_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```